# laravel or lumen, which one to choose?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am a student and I'm making a project, an application which will show data to users on web end and also on android application. but I am confuse which one to choose for backend development, Laravel or Lumen ? My application will have signup function and displayed data from mysql against search queries. There will be 4 to 5 tables and multiple columns in each table. also images to show. So which one I should choose?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described so far Laravel seems like a perfect fit. Start off with laravel, if you need more speed and a framework focused towards building web services give lumen a try. If you haven't worked with PHP or any other backend app before, go with vanilla PHP.

Goodluck with the app!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to build an API use Lumen, otherwise Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend `Laravel` rather than `Lumen` (Frankly speaking, [CI](http://codeigniter.org.cn) framework may be more suitable, which is simpler and friendly to new user). About 1.5 years ago, I experienced the same dilemma, just like you. For lacking of enough document, I have to migrate my project from `Lumen` to `Laravel` when I came across some problems.